# Split rows values into multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need to split "Group" into "Value1" and "Value2" from the table below:

[image]

The first 3 columns are identical, so I'd like to have a table like:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | A Value | B Value
```

I know I can create two references of this table, filter by "Group" and then merge them back together, but isn't there a better way?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to select the `Group` column in the query editor and click Transform > Pivot Column with `Value` as your Values Column.

[image: Pivot Column]

The result should look like this:

[image: Output]